# For the reflection $\phi$ in the sphere $S(a,r)$ it holds that $\phi(B^n) = B^n$ if and only if $\phi(a*) = 0$

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, reflection, inversive-geometry

This is a question about Theorem 3.4.2 in "Geometry of discrete groups" from Beardon.
Let $\phi$ be the reflection in a sphere $S(a,r)$ for $a \in \hat{\mathbb{R}^n}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Then TFAE:

1. $S(a,r)$ and $S^{n-1}$ are orthogonal
2. $\phi(a*) = 0$
3. $\phi(B^n) = B^n$.

where $a* := \frac{a}{{\lVert a \rVert}^2}$

I understand that 1 is equivalent to 2. But I don't understand why $3 \implies 2$.
And in the proof of the implication $1+2 \implies 3 \:$ I do not understand the step

$\frac{r^2\cdot |x-a*|}{|x-a|\cdot|a*-a|} = \frac{|a|\cdot|x-a*|}{|x-a|}$

In the calculations. Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: What is $a^*$ and what is $\Phi$?

Comment: Hey Berci thank you for your comment. $\Phi$ instead of $\phi$ was a typo. And I defined $a*$. Sorry I thought that was standard notation

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me. So, $\phi$ is an *inversion* with respect to the sphere $S(a,r)$ and $S^{n-1}=S(0,1)$ and $B^n$ is the closed ball of $S(0,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly right

Comment: Do you already know that inversions preserve angles? This provides an easy geometric proof of equivalence of 1 and 3.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Yes we do know that !

Comment: Well, can you then prove geometrically that 1 implies 3? Use only this "angle" property (and, of course, the fact that spheres map to spheres).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence of 1) <-> 3) can be found in Thm.4.4.6 of the book "Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds" by John G.Ratcliffe.